# Filling out a web form programatically in c#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, http-post, smart-device

I have a web application that fills out some information into text boxes and hits a button. I am now trying to turn it into an app for a smart device running Windows CE. My code is as follows:

```
string doc = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
HtmlElement userValue = doc.GetElementById("username");
userValue.SetAttribute("value", "devacc");
HtmlElement passValue = doc.GetElementById("password");
passValue.SetAttribute("value", "zzq15354");
HtmlElement subButton = doc.GetElementById("submit");
subButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

Is there a way I can do this so it will run in Windows CE?

Post Request:

```
string postData = "?username=uname&password=pass";
byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/" + postData);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
     stream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
string s = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

**Edit: I'm thinking I'll do it with a post request, but I'm still confused on how I'll pass in the username/password**

**Edit x2: I've included what I have so far of the post request. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything but I think that postData is wrong.**

Comment: Per your update you do it the same way you do any other post request, you just need to find the field names in the html source of the page you are connecting to . If you included some example HTML or a link to the page you are trying to log in to we could help you with the code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm trying to log into the surveymonkey api. Where would I find the necessary field names in the HTML?

Comment: Just as a FYI, they are using OAuth. 99.9% of all OAuth implementations that I have seen state that what you are doing is not allowed (typing the username and password in for the user) and if they detect that you are doing it your API key will be revoked and anyone who uses your program will suddenly have their program stop working. (the entire point of OAuth is you never give your username and password to the program that is wanting to access your account information)

Comment: @ctacke that's from the same project I'm working on, but rather then trying to convert the original code, I'm trying to post the data to the site, which I believe is possible in this framework.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain oh, thanks, I didn't know that. I'll try to find another way then.

Comment: I would check with the company, some sites provide exemptions for mobile devices (I assume you are using one because your question is tagged [tag:Windows-CE]) because on some devices it is impossible to launch a browser and get the callback url back from it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Youre correct, it is a mobile device. I'll check with them, because I'm not really sure how else to do this.